# Addings functions to an array in swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I was wondering is it possible to add functions to an array in swift?, And if so how would I go about doing that, an example would be helpful.

thankyou in advance

```
    enum MyFunc{
    case Arity0 (Void ->Void) 


}

var cycle = Array<MyFunc>()
```

to add to the array:

```
    func addToArray(){

    cycle.append(MyFunc.Arity0(ani1))
    cycle.append(MyFunc.Arity0(ani2))
    cycle.append(MyFunc.Arity0(ani3))
    cycle.append(MyFunc.Arity0(ani4))
    cycle.append(MyFunc.Arity0(ani5))

}
```

Comment: I think you should clarify the question.  Do you want to make an array of functions or do you want to extend the "functionality" of an Array type?  Both are possible.

Comment: @Eppilo , my reason for asking this question, is that i have a set of 5 images on screen that i have animated, they are the all same image, and i wanted each image to loop one by one, and then repeat. each of the images has a function which allows the animation to occur, i though it may be best(and i may be wrong here), that if i place the functions in to an array, i may be able to animate each image individually one after another (sorry for the long reply)

Comment: So if understand correctly you want to declare an array of functions.  All you need to do is is to put the function signature in the square brackets and initialise. Example: " [()->()]() "

Comment: @Eppilo so would the above (added code) be another way of adding my functions to the array. my functions do not return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an array of functions, and each function does not take parameters and returns noting you can do:

```
var cycle = [()->()]()
cycle.append(nameOfYourFunctionNoBrackets)
```